# Android Pay API - get payment methods

Tags: android, payment

I'm developing an Android application and I need to get user's credit cards/payment methods like in the picture below

[image]

is there a way I can do this with Android Pay API or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. In fact, there's significant documentation on exactly what you need to do. Here's a link to start:

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/get-started